# Remove random object from array

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing a small quiz app, for the improving my objective-c skills. i've reached a problem with making sure it do not pick the same questions. (atm its just letters, but it should be questions and options).

After r = arc4random() % [myList count]; is performed i need to remove that object from the mylist array and questions array how can i do this?

```
NSArray *questions = @[ @[ @"r",@"t", @"h", @"f", @"g", @"r" ], @[ @"D", @"E", @"F", @"Q", @"X", @"F" ], @[ @"G", @"H", @"I", @"T", @"U", @"I" ] ];

NSArray *myList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
for (int i=0; i<[questions count]; i++)
{
    myList = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}

r = arc4random() % [myList count];
```

Comment: Hint:  Review the spec for NSArray, then go up to the initial descriptive text for NSArray and click on NSMutableArray, then review that.  Your questions are answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use NSMutableArray and [removeObjectAtIndex](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex%3a).

`[array removeObjectAtIndex:r];`